# One Magento, One Catalog, Multple Domains, Multi Language, Shared Shopping Cart, SSL on Checkout

Tags: magento, cross-domain, cart

**This is what I’m trying to achieve on our dedicated server (Direct Admin):**

1 Magento (1.6.2.0)

1 catalog

3 domains

- domain.nl (is main and has the magento files)
- domain.de (is domain alias, not Virtual Host, has no files at all)
- domain.se (is domain alias, not Virtual Host, has no files at all)

3 languages

- Dutch
- German
- Swedish

Shared Shopping Cart

SSL on Chekout

**Let’s say** a Dutch visitor is typing “product X” in Google and finds his product on our German site (domain.de). He adds it to the cart and likes to continue in Dutch. So he clicks the Dutch flag and should be able to checkout on domain.nl.

**I tried** a couple of things with the language. **One way** I had 3 websites, 1 for each domain and all with 3 stores, one for each language. So 9 stores and views in total. This was the only way I could get the flags showing. But most of the time the flag image was not showing because the code of the view had to be the 2 letter country code, which can only used once. And when I changed language (thus domain), the cart was not shared.

**The other way** I had 1 Website with 3 stores, one store and view for each language/domain. But in this case the language selector (flags) where not showing at all.

**I’ve been reading** allot about this. But all the (mostly old) topics or article I found are about a single subject and so different from each other that I cannot combine them into one.

**Thanks for any help!!**

Cheers,
Robert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have played with this concept a bit and I believe this is how you would do it. Under Magento Admin->System->Manage Stores you would set up the following.

- One Website (most likely Main Website)
- One Store
- Three Store Views (One for each language)

Then you will swing into System->Configuration. Select each specific language in the "Current Configuration Scope" then change General->Web->Unsecure->Base URL and General->Web->Secure->Base URL to the URL you want to use for each store. i.e. Your German configuration should not use the Website Setting and should be set to domain.de instead.

For each of your virtual hosts, configure them to all point to your single Magento install. When they come in with the specific URL Magento should route them to the proper language version and, if they select a flag, it should change to the other URL for that language.

Give this a try and let me know what your results are. I have only lightly played with this and have referenced these topics. I agree with you that this is an area that sometimes has too many ways it can be configured and not enough recommended ways.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/227246/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/multiple-website-setup